# How to write karate-config.js file? Give detailed information please

Tags: config, karate

Where we find and edit `karate.log()`, `karate.env` and `karate.configure()` files ?

Answer (score 2):

Kindly refer to the official documentation: [Configuration](https://github.com/intuit/karate#configuration)